# File doesn't show up in TYPO3 Fileadmin

Tags: file, typo3

is TYPO3 doing some indexing of the filesystem into database?
We try to add a video to our page here, but video isn't selecable from the file window altough its put into the right directory.
The Fileadmin says "9 records found" in the folder and is displaying only 7 Files, because someone might have deleted two of the files out of the folder.
But the new video file we've put there won't be displayed, too.

Is there any way to manually start TYPO3s file indexer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, I feel stupid right now - altough I can't really explain the behavior...
What happened seemes to be some strange caching failure.

If you click on the "choose file" button it shows the window as seen in the screenshot above, displaying the last used folder.
But: this view is somehow cached.
If you select the same folder again from the file tree from the left, the view is updated and the missing files are shown -.-

Answer (score 0):

I don't think TYPO3 does any indexing of the files; it just reads the list of the files straight off the filesystem.  So there's no file indexer to start.

My suggestion for your problem would be to check the permissions on the file you uploaded and make sure it's readable by whatever user the Web server is running as ('apache', 'www-data', etc).  If it isn't readable by the Web server it won't show up in the fileadmin area.

Comment: Hey,
we've checked that already (forgot to mention it, sorry) - we even set the rights to 0777 and testet the access for HTTP and PHP - both worked fine.

The indexing came to my mind because of the label saying "9 records found" at the top of the window, altough only 7 of the former 9 files remained.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  Where are you seeing this "X records found" language?  I don't see it in the fileadmin area in any of my TYPO3 sites.  Maybe an old version of TYPO3?  Anyway -- another thing to try would be clearing all the system caches (lightning bolt icon, top right) and rebuilding the DB reference table (Admin Tools -> DB check -> Manage Reference Index).

Comment: I'm assuming if you something considering records you are probably using DAM. DAM is an extension that takes over the file management, this actually does index each file. However this should not give any problems with files being invisible. Is the file you want to select actually in an allowed format?

Comment: Clearing the TYPO3 Cache (Frontend/Backend) was one of the first things i've tried, too, since this fixes the most mistakes in typo3 for some reason...
The DB-Check in the Admin-Tools didn't do the trick, sadly :(
Here is a screenshot of my fileadmin-window where it says "9 records found": http://share.envy.de/fileadmin.jpg

Comment: What version of TYPO3 are you using?  Are you using any extensions like DAM, etc that modify file handling?